# vue.js Generator (API Platform)

Tags: json, vue.js, api-platform.com

Please, I need a solution.
I followed Vue.js Generator ([API-Platform](https://api-platform.com/docs/client-generator/vuejs/#vuejs-generator)) for an easy API consumption but I still have an error when I execute the command "yarn run dev" the browser shows "faild to fetch"

**[result]**[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwnIJ.png)

Comment: Hi, we need more context to help you, but it looks like your server is not serving your data, do you have the php api-platform running?

Comment: Hi, I created vuejs project and I used this command to generate an existent resource ($ generate-api-platform-client -g vue https://demo.api-platform.com src/ --resource review), offered by the api-platform.

Comment: did you try adding the full URL? `generate-api-platform-client -g vue https://demo.api-platform.com src/ --resource review`

Comment: I followed the documentation step by step and I generated the full URL and it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the console saying ? You should see the request made to the server in the Network tab of your devtools, and the response from the server.

Comment: I solved the problem in fact I tried to consume another resource that I created with a PHP and API-Platform and it works very well, thanks for your answers.